# How to find all repetition groups using regex findall?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `text = 'change of use of fidg to idvr change of use ohdgt to ousd'`, how can I use `re.findall` to give such output `[('change of use of fidg', 'to idvr'), ('change of use ohdgt', 'to ousd')]`?

I've tried `re.findall('(change of use .*?) (to .*?)',text)`, but the output is `re.findall('(change of use .*?) (to .*?)',planning_note)`

Comment: A [mcve] would be hepful

Answer (score 1):

You might assert `change` or `to` or the end of the string at the right using a positive lookahead, and capture the values in group 1.

Using *re.findall* will return the group values.

```
\s*(.+?)(?=\s+(?:change|to)\b|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nhgQyx/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"\s*(.+?)(?=\s+(?:change|to)\b|$)"
s = "change of use of fidg to idvr change of use ohdgt to ousd"

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['change of use of fidg', 'to idvr', 'change of use ohdgt', 'to ousd']
```